# SQL Query - Pull data from ambiguous column names for growth/decline %

Tags: mysql

Re-post due to bad data set and bad formatting. I am trying to divide data from two separate tables that have ambiguous column names.

I am newer to SQL, I know it should be simple, however I just can not figure it out. So far I have tried to rename columns, alias columns, union the table, and select multiple data sets.

I keep hitting roadblocks.

I am trying to measure growth or decline week over week. Ideally I want to take the total sales for Plates and do the following equation: (75/100-1) which would equal a -25% decline from last week.

What would be the best way to go about this?

The two example tables are below

---

```
LastWeekData

Product       Day        Month        TotalSales

Plates         7           3            $100
Spoons         7           3            $150
Forks          7           3            $120
```

---

```
CurrentData

Product       Day        Month        TotalSales

Plates         14           3            $75
Spoons         14           3            $100
Forks          14           3            $115
```

Comment: Why do you say that the tables have ambiguous column names? What are the two tables? Is there data in the table for Day 8, 9, .. 13 or just multiples of 7? Also, your calculation doesn't seem correct. I believe it should be `((75-100)/100)*100`

Comment: Are the two things you've put in your question your desired output data, or the content of your tables?  Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: @clinomaniac;  
(75/100-1)*100 is the same with (75-100)/100)*100

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ `((75-100)/100)*100` is different from what is in the question. Read as `((CurrentSales - LastWeekSales)/LastWeekSales)*100. The equation in the question only works because LastWeekSales = 100.

Comment: @clinomaniac I edited my post, the two tables are below, not my desired output. Sorry for the confusion. The equation (x/y -1) is the desired equation. It will output the percentage of growth/decline week to week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table alias to differentiate the table columns that you want to display. See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b0d81/29

```
select cur.Product, 
       cur.Day,
       cur.Month, 
       cur.TotalSales as currweek_TotalSales,
       pre.TotalSales as lastweek_TotalSales,
       round((cur.TotalSales/pre.TotalSales-1)*100) as percent_change
from CurrentData as cur  
inner join LastWeekData as pre
on pre.product=cur.product
where datediff(str_to_date(concat_ws('-','0001',cur.month,cur.day),'%Y-%m-%d'),
             str_to_date(concat_ws('-','0001',pre.month,pre.day),'%Y-%m-%d'))
             = 7

Result:
Product Day Month   currweek_TotalSales lastweek_TotalSales percent_change
Plates  14  3        75                 100                -25
Spoons  14  3       100                 150                -33 
Forks   14  3       115                 120                 -4
```